# Make the menu button slide with the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a side menu bar which toggles with the press of a menu button, but the issue I'm facing here is that I want the menu button to slide to left as the side menu slides off and again move back to same position when menu slides in, hoping to get some help from SO..

Here is my code please let me know if I went wrong somewere,

**.html**

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>SLDS Nav-Bar</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
            <style>
            /*Basic styling*/
            html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #eee;
            }

            #header{
                margin-left: 218px;
                width: 59.88em;
                margin-bottom: -3em;
            }

            .menu-button{
                font-size:2em;
            }
            /*Additional slds styling*/
            .slds-nav--size{
                width: 218px;
                border-right: 1px solid #d8dde6;
                background:white;
                height: 50.96em;
            }
            /*Media Queries*/
           @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            /* For mobile phones: */
                [class*="slds-nav--size"] {
                        transform: translate(-218px);
                }
            }
            </style>
            <!--Script's gose here-->
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script>
                // ==========================================================================
                // Animate for menu toggle
                // ==========================================================================
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(".menu-button").click(function(){
                            $(".toggle-menu").toggle("drop",300);
                        });
                    });
            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
    <header id="header">
        <div class="">
          <a class="menu-button">☰</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--vertical slds-navigation-list--vertical slds-navigation-list--vertical-inverse slds-nav--size toggle-menu">
      <h2 class="slds-text-title--caps slds-p-around--medium" id="search-results">Search Results</h2>
      <ul>
        <li class="slds-is-active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Top Results</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Accounts</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Opportunities</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Leads</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Groups</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Files</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Dashboards</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Feeds</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h2 class="slds-text-title--caps slds-p-around--medium" id="external-results">External Results</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App One</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the menu is clicked, I add a class to the header. The class in CSS defines the `margin-left` to be 10px. When the menu is clicked again, it goes back to the original position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-button").click(function() {
    $(".toggle-menu").toggle("drop", 300);
    $("#header").toggleClass("to-the-left");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#header {
  margin-left: 218px;
  width: 59.88em;
  margin-bottom: -3em;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

#header.to-the-left {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-button {
  font-size: 2em;
}


/*Additional slds styling*/

.slds-nav--size {
  width: 218px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8dde6;
  background: white;
  height: 50.96em;
}


/*Media Queries*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="slds-nav--size"] {
    transform: translate(-218px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <div class="">
    <a class="menu-button">☰</a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--vertical slds-navigation-list--vertical slds-navigation-list--vertical-inverse slds-nav--size toggle-menu">
  <h2 class="slds-text-title--caps slds-p-around--medium" id="search-results">Search Results</h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="slds-is-active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Top Results</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Accounts</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Opportunities</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Leads</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Groups</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Files</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Dashboards</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Feeds</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2 class="slds-text-title--caps slds-p-around--medium" id="external-results">External Results</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App One</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Lol, I literally just finished putting together a fiddle (doing the same thing), came back, and saw your answer :D. Btw, if you add `transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in 0s;` to `.menu-button` it will match the speed and easing of the menu's slide :)

Comment: Quite surprised you're using JS with it when this can be achieved sometimes better by straight CSS3

Comment: @Option Agreed. But the OP used the "drop" feature from jQuery-UI which is less easy to simulate with CSS.

Comment: But one more question if you wont mind :-)....when screen size reduces how will i make side menu hide and just show the menu button and display menu only once button is pressed

Comment: I changed the max-width of the media query from 768 to 400 so the side-menu would be visible here when run is clicked. When it is 768 pixels, the side-menu won't be visible on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Your #header have margin-left: 218px and you don't do anything with this when you change menu display. I modify your code and use CSS transition for this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SLDS Nav-Bar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <style>
        /*Basic styling*/
        html,
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        #header{
            width: 59.88em;
            margin: 0 0 -3em 0;
            -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.3s linear;
            -moz-transition: margin-left 0.3s linear;
            transition: margin-left 0.3s linear;
        }

        #header.nav-open {
            margin-left: 218px;
        }

        .menu-button{
            font-size:2em;
        }
        /*Additional slds styling*/
        .slds-nav--size{
            position: relative;
            left: -218px;
            width: 218px;
            border-right: 1px solid #d8dde6;
            background:white;
            height: 50.96em;
            -webkit-transition: left 0.3s linear;
            -moz-transition: left 0.3s linear;
            transition: left 0.3s linear;
        }

        .slds-nav--size.open {
            left: 0;
        }
        /*Media Queries*/
       @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        /* For mobile phones: */
            [class*="slds-nav--size"] {
                    transform: translate(-218px);
            }
        }
        </style>
        <!--Script's gose here-->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            // ==========================================================================
            // Animate for menu toggle
            // ==========================================================================
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".menu-button").click(function(){
                        $("#header").toggleClass('nav-open');
                        $(".slds-nav--size").toggleClass('open');
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<header id="header">
    <div class="">
      <a class="menu-button">☰</a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--vertical slds-navigation-list--vertical slds-navigation-list--vertical-inverse slds-nav--size toggle-menu">
  <h2 class="slds-text-title--caps slds-p-around--medium" id="search-results">Search Results</h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="slds-is-active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Top Results</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Accounts</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Opportunities</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Leads</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Groups</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Files</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Dashboards</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="search-results">Feeds</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2 class="slds-text-title--caps slds-p-around--medium" id="external-results">External Results</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App One</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="external-results">App Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```